# Using javascript map with a function that has two arguments

Tags: javascript

I know that I can use `map` with a function of one variable in the following manner:

```
var squarefunc = function(x) {
    return x*x;
};
values = [1,2,3,4]
values.map(squarefunc) // returns [1,4,9,16]
```

How do I use `map` with the following function:

```
var squarefuncwithadjustment = function(x, adjustment) {
    return (x*x + adjustment);
}
```

where, I want to input value for argument `adjustment` manually when I call map, say `adjustment=2`, and have the value of `x` taken from the array `values`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use an anonymous function:

```
values.map(
  function(x) { return squarefuncwithadjustment(x, 2); }
);
```

Comment: this initiates the promise rather than saving it for the Promise.all(). How can I set and consume the promise declaratively?

Answer (score 55):

You could use a callback creation function:

```
var createSquareFuncWithAdjustment = function(adjustment) {
    return function(x) { return (x * x) + adjustment; };
};

values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
values.map(createSquareFuncWithAdjustment(2)); // returns [3, 6, 11, 18]
```

Comment: This is the solution that solves the wider problem of passing ancilliary parameters to a map-reduce chain, so gets my vote.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat is this an example of a closure ?

Comment: @Courtney I’ve never fully figured out what a closure is, but I would guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @Courtney every function in JavaScript will close over the scope in which it was defined. In this specific case the inner anonymous function preserves access to the adjustment argument.

Answer (score 38):

As of ES6 you can use:

```
.map(element => fn(element, params))
```

In your case if I want to use 3 as adjustment:

```
values = [1,2,3,4]
values.map(n => squarefuncwithadjustment(n, 3))
```

Answer (score 10):

If you reverse the order of your arguments, you can bind the adjustment as the first argument, so that the `x` will be passed as the second.

```
var squarefuncwithadjustment = function(adjustment, x) {
    return (x*x + adjustment);
}

values.map(squarefuncwithadjustment.bind(null, 2)); // [3, 6, 11, 18]
```

The first argument to `.bind` sets the calling context, which doesn't matter here, so I used `null`. The second argument to `.bind` binds `2` as the first argument when invoked.

It may be better to store the function as a bound version.

```
var squareFuncWith2 = squarefuncwithadjustment.bind(null, 2);
```

Then use it with `.map`.

```
values.map(squareFuncWith2); // [3, 6, 11, 18]
```

Answer (score 5):

Well!! You can easily pass a second parameter to the map function. The following method is widely used to pass this parameter which generally gets hidden during the call:

```
values.map(function(x , this) {
    return x*x + this.adjustment;
});

var adjustment = 1;
var values = [1,2,3,4]
values.map(function(x , adjustment) {
    return x*x + adjustment;
});
```

> OR

```
var adjustment = 1;
var squarefunc = function(x , adjustment) {
    return x*x + adjustment;
};
values = [1,2,3,4]
values.map(squarefunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform this within a single function, you can add a dash of IIFE to your Curry.

```js
function mapSingleFunc(values, adjustment) {
  return values.map((adjustment => x => (x * x) + adjustment)(adjustment));
};
console.log(mapSingleFunc([1,2,3,4], 2))
```

In the most abstract sense you are able to tunnel your `values` in through the calling array. Adding an IIFE allows you to feed the `adjustment` in each time in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

ES6+ :

```
values.map( x => squarefuncwithadjustment(x,2) );
```

Answer (score -2):

`var squarefuncwithadjustment = (x, adjustment) => {
    return (x*x + adjustment);
}`

Then

`values = values.map(
  x => squarefuncwithadjustment(x, 2)
);`